# Can an expression such as ([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}) be simplified?

Tags: regex

In other words, "only match either 2 digits or 4 digits". The expression in the title works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner-looking way using operators I don't know about because I'm only just learning regex.

Comment: What language/regex dialect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular regex can be rewritten to

```
(\d{2}){1,2}
```

or even (for small values of 2 and 4)

```
\d\d(\d\d)?
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution. I think `(\d{2}){1,2}` is really a simplification.

Comment: Your first example is definitely more readable than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do you like

```
([0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{2})?)
```

better? I am not sure if this is simpler, but different.

But if you want to match exactly 2 or 4 digits, you need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your expression. Otherwise you will get partial matches on everything, that has at least 2 digits in it. Something like this

```
 ^([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$
```

or this

```
 \b([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})\b
```

See this [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32t6c)

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten in another form, yes. Simplified, no.

Answer (score 1):

Atmost you can do this

```
(\d{2}|\d{4})
```

Comment: That is not the same in all regex flavors.

Comment: Some (I think at least .NET) treat it as "any Unicode digit".

Comment: u r right..in `.net` `\d` depends upon the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread's` current culture..but that is a required behavior..cheers to `.net`